# How to convert string to DateTime in C# EF Core query

Tags: entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, postgresql-9.1, ef-core-3.0

```
var res = Context.Exampletable
                 .Where(s => s.CompanyId == CompanyId &&  
                             Convert.ToDateTime(s.TextDate) >= DateTime.Now)
                 .Select(x => new Exampletable { TextDate = x.TextDate })
                 .FirstOrDefault();
```

This is the Linq for one of my problem statements. I want to fetch records future date records from current date & timestamp, so I am converting and comparing it to `Datetime` but I get this error:

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet
>   .Where(a => Convert.ToDateTime(a.TextDate) > Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now))'   > could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync()

Note: in Postgresql DB `TextDate` column has string datatype and contains values like '4/1/2020 10:00 AM'.

Please provide a solution for this.

Comment: It's not working because Postgresql's LINQ to Entities implementation doesn't know how to convert `Convert.ToDateTime(string)` to SQL

Answer (score 6):

If you *really* can't change the underlying column type, then instead of unsupported `Convert.ToDateTime` use C# cast operator which maps to PostgreSQL `CAST` operator:

```
(DateTime)(object)s.TextDate >= DateTime.Now
```

Note that the "intermediate" cast to `object` is needed just to make the C# compiler happy.

---

P.S. I really have no idea why some methods of `Convert` like `ToInt32` are supported, and other like `ToDateTime` are not. I guess just yet another EF Core inconsistency.

Comment: Ivan Stoev thnk you for the suggestion, i tried this and LinQ is now translating into the SQL but its only fetching mated records like TextDate== DateTime.Now  and >= , <= not giving correct output

Comment: That would be surprising since cast converts the string to timestamp data type, so the comparison should be using timestamp rules. Let make sure you are using it correctly, for instance the above translates to `CAST(t."TextDate" AS timestamp without time zone) < NOW()`, how looks the SQL part that "not giving a correct output"?

Comment: The full list of supported functions are listed here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/functions

You can use EF CORE value converters achieve the above https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions

The reason why CAST is supported though the value converters but not CONVERT is an interesting one. I assume it is because CONVERT might give inconsistent results in different database providers.

If you need to use the CONVERT SQL Server function, you can give this approach a try https://stackoverflow.com/a/68729840/422427

Comment: @DasithWijes The question is about PostgreSQL ([Npgsql provider](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL)), so the Sql Server function mappings are irrelevant. What about value converters, these are *not* applicable for this scenario, as they will try to convert the DateTime parameter to string rather than string column to DateTime.

Comment: @IvanStoev the value converters will convert String to DateTime or vice versa. Check them out if you're not sure. The generated SQL will use the CAST operation to convert strings to date time and then do the >= operation.  Your suggested solution has the additional draw back that it doesn't work with the InMemory DB while the value converter approach correctly works for both scenarios.

Comment: @DasithWijes I'm watch EF Core with its internals from the very beginning, so I think I know a little how the things work. And what are you showing is not what it does. Not sure where are you getting these conclusions, but if I have `DateTime` property configured with `.HasConversion<string>`, and use 'DateTime.Now` inside query I get `[Column] >= GETDATE()`, and if I use `DateTime` parameter, then `[Column] >= >= @__dtNow_0` where `DECLARE @__dtNow_0 nvarchar(48) = '2022-01-22 18:10:59.8576905';`. As you can see, there is no cast and the parameter type is string as I expect. So is comparing..

Comment: ... strings. Which is not what is in this question. Looks like you are speaking for a different EF Core than me:-) Mine is official, and value converters work this way from the beginning up to including the latest at this time EFC 6.0. So check your SQL again :-)

Comment: @IvanStoev rather than appealing to authority why don't you post a github example and I can see what you're doing differently to me. I can definitely generate the SQL I posted in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It always baffles me that people decide to store DateTime values as strings and then order users of the database to do calculations with the values. I can imagine you'd like to curse the person who decided to do this, especially because he decided to store it in this non-sortable fashion.

### Best solution

If possible, change the database such that it stores DateTimes as DateTimes, or if your database language doesn't know how to do that, store the Ticks of the DateTimes as longs. Future users of the database will glorify your name!

```
long nowTicks = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
var result = Context.Exampletable
    .Where(example => example.CompanyId == CompanyId && example.DateTicks >= nowTicks);
```

### Almost best solution

if the decision to save DateTimes as strings is a decision of the developers of PostgreSQL, then try to find if they have functions to handle these datetimes, especially comparison

### The "it's getting worse" solution

Try to find out if PostgreSQL has string manipulation functions, so you can translate 4/1/2020 10:00 AM into something IComparable. It is difficult if you want to write code to compare this value with for example 4/1/2019 10:00 AM, or 4/2/2020 10:00 AM, so I guess it will be hell of a job to do this in SQL

Comment: Harald Coppoolse : Thanku for this ultimate solution,, i created the Datetimetick column and storing the tikcs value of datetime as suggested by and it worked perfectly. I am able to fetch the accurate records. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

With EF Core 5+ you can use ValueConverters as a "workaround" for this scenario and use the built in StringDateTimeConverter (https://apisof.net/catalog/e0dd77d4-73c3-6bba-e51a-4842a59894d1).

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<Exampletable>()
        .Property(e => e.TextDate)
        .HasConversion<string>();
}

public class ExampleTable
{
 public DateTime TextDate {get; set;}
}
```

Then simply

```cs
DateTimeOffset someValue = some-value-here;
var query = DbContext.Entities.Where(e => e.TextDate <= someValue);
```

It is important that the parameter inside your LINQ query is a datetimeoffset for this to work as EF CORE doesn't generate a SQL with CAST operation for the column if you don't. See here for an example https://gist.github.com/dasiths/19b885c58442226d9fc8b89bc78511e4

The generated SQL will be like

```sql
((@__startSearch_0 >= CAST([s].[TextDate]) AS datetimeoffset))
```

Edit: To reiterate, using value converters is a "workaround" here. To see a full analysis of the options, I've written a full detailed analysis of the "work arounds" with the value converter hack here https://dasith.me/2022/01/23/ef-core-datetime-conversion-rabbit-hole/.

Comment: No, the generated SQL is different and has no cast, try again.

Comment: @IvanStoev I don't know what EF Core version you're using but the one I'm using definitely generates that.

Comment: I'm using the official EFC 6.0.1 / SqlServer. And it's not generating that from your class. Hehe, weird actually. But see, your post is inconsistent. `DateTime.Now` inside L2E query never generates parameter as you claim your SQL query contains.

Comment: For DateTime.Now I used a Param rather than directly in query as shown. Maybe that's where the difference is then? But you said it doesn't work for param too?

Comment: It doesn't. See, I took you class (just added `public int Id { get; set; }` to make EFC happy, then the same fluent config, then LINQ query `var dtNow = DateTime.Now;  var q = db.Set<ExampleTable>().Where(e => e.TextDate >= dtNow && e.TextDate <= DateTime.Now)` just to test both. And I'm getting `DECLARE @__dtNow_0 nvarchar(48) = N'2022-01-22 18:39:34.7871451';  SELECT [e].[Id], [e].[TextDate]
FROM [ExampleTable] AS [e]
WHERE ([e].[TextDate] >= @__dtNow_0) AND ([e].[TextDate] <= GETDATE())`

Comment: I can only confirm @Ivan's findings, no idea how your findings can be different. It seems we aren't aware of some circumstance that makes EF switch. Note that, in view of sargability, the query without converting the database value makes far more sense than the reverse, so I guess it's more likely to be EF's standard implementation.

Comment: @IvanStoev I spent last night setting up with sample. Can you run it and see what it generates. 

https://gist.github.com/dasiths/19b885c58442226d9fc8b89bc78511e4

I think I know what the difference is. I was using a datetimeoffset parameter (SomeValue) inside my LINQ query when testing rather than a datetime. EF Core uses the CAST to convert the column value to datetime offset before comparing.

I don't know if this is intended behaviour or a bug on EF Core's part. I will update my answer to indicate that.

Comment: @GertArnold my "SomeValue" parameter inside the LINQ query above was a DateTimeOffset. I think that made all the difference. It's weird but I made a gist to demo it https://gist.github.com/dasiths/19b885c58442226d9fc8b89bc78511e4

Comment: @DasithWijes That's another story. Yes, it generates what you say. However this is not because of the value conversion (you can remove `HasConversion<string>()` and get pretty much the same cast inside SQL), but because C# emits hidden implicit conversions from `DateTimeOffset` to `DateTime` inside LINQ query expression tree, which then are translated as `CAST`s. So, to recap, value conversion is not a solution for this problem. In fact there is no solution - my *workaround* works only for some providers. Of course the best is people to store their dates as dates instead of strings.

Comment: @IvanStoev yes the value converter only allows us to use the implicit conversion inside .NET or LINQ->Objects provider and does not do anything for generating the query as the target types EF CORE uses are [datetime] -> [datetimeoffset] from inside the expression tree. But this allows us to have a `DateTime` field in the entity rather than a string and it does work with In-Memory provider too. The point is that value conveter does give us the option to have a datetime field. Totally agree that this is a hack. There is no alternative to storing datetime as the proper data type or as ticks.