# Convert String to DateTime in LINQ query with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, date, entity-framework-core

Using EF Core 5 and SQL Server, I am trying to figure how to convert a date stored as a string in LINQ query (so on SQL Server side).

I have searched in `EF.Functions` but I was unable to find the proper method for such date parsing.

I have also tried `Convert.ToDateTime` and `DateTime.Parse`, but they seem both to not have LINQ translations.

The direct SQL equivalent is `Convert(datetime, mycolumn, 102)`.
I would be really surprised if Microsoft did nothing to support something as simple and easy to use in native SQL, so I'm sorry if I miss something obvious, but I have searched on the web and did a few attempts before to surrender.

PS : please note that I am aware of workarounds like calling ToList() before to apply Where(), or to modify the DB (or create a view) to change the column type.

My question is mainly : how to call with EF `Convert(datetime, mycolumn, 102)`

Comment: Why do you need to do the conversion _in sql_? What data type is the column in your db and the datatype you want in c#?

Comment: Dates are stored in string, and I need to convert them on SQL side just to be able to do some tests on them before to retrieve the records, or apply a .Min() on them. 
The string can directly be converted to a date with the method I said.

Comment: "or to modify the DB (or create a view) to fix the problem." I mean, if it hurts when you hit your head against the wall, don't put up a pillow. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/functions#date-and-time-functions) is the listing of what EF can convert to MS Sql Server.

Comment: @gunr2171 thanks for the link. And apparently Microsoft didn't supplied natively a method to do this. Maybe in an additional package more aimed toward SQL Server ? This seem so basic...

Comment: Why aren't the dates stored in a `date` or `datetime` colum in the first place?

Comment: Storing dates in the database using the proper data type is not a "workaround" it is the correct solution. What you are trying to do is the workaround. If you store the dates properly (or even add a computed column to enforce integrity and give you a column to use with the correct type e.g. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5ff31dfc506a5c41667c3ed333e9721b)) then your problem goes away, and you don't need to worry about a workaround here, or any other time you need to treat your date as an actual date rather than a string

Comment: The answer is "you can't because Microsoft doesn't support weird scenarios where you're using the DBMS incorrectly".

Comment: @IanKemp in this case we can also throw to trash all other cast/convert methods in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/functions#date-and-time-functions ...

Comment: @Charlieface tables were created by Bulk Insert without control other the column type. The question is not "how to improve the design of this DB", but thanks anyway for all comments related to this...

Comment: What EF Core version are you using?

Comment: You could create your own function to do the conversion `CREATE FUNCTION MyConv (@value varchar(100)) RETURNS date AS BEGIN RETURN CONVERT(datetime, @value, 102); END;` but for that price you may as well add a computed column: `ALTER TABLE ADD MyDate AS CONVERT(datetime, mycolumn, 102);`

Comment: @IvanStoev 5.0.8, as said in question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can relatively easily add the desired unsupported method using the EF Core scalar function mapping.

For instance, add the following class (with the necessary usings):

```cs
namespace Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
{
    public static class SqlFunctions
    {
        public static DateTime? ToDateTime(this string s, int format) => throw new NotSupportedException();

        public static ModelBuilder AddSqlFunctions(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(() => ToDateTime(default, default))
                .HasTranslation(args => new SqlFunctionExpression(
                    functionName: "CONVERT",
                    arguments: args.Prepend(new SqlFragmentExpression("date")),
                    nullable: true,
                    argumentsPropagateNullability: new[] { false, true, false }),
                    type: typeof(DateTime),
                    typeMapping: null));

            return modelBuilder;
        }
    }
}
```

The second method is for convenience and does the actual mapping.

Now all you need is to call it from `OnModelCreating` override:

```cs
if (Database.IsSqlServer()) modelBuilder.AddSqlFunctions();
```

and then use it inside the LINQ to Entities query:

```cs
var query = db.Set<MyEntity>()
    .Where(e => e.MyProp.ToDateTime(102) > DateTime.Today
    .ToQueryString();
// SELECT ..... WHERE Convert(date, [e].[MyProp], 102) > CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Thank's for the example of custom sql function. I'm gonna use it if everybody confirms there's no built-in function for this. 
Despite the lack of a native solution, eventually, are you aware of a nuget package (possibly dedicated to sql server) that adds this kind of things to improve SQL Server features support in EFCore ? I had a look but did not found anything relevant. Thank you.

Comment: (1) There is no "out-of-the-box" solution so far. What you see in the link is what they support. In general, their system of extending `EF.Functions` with provider (database) specific methods is far from perfect, in case you target multiple databases. The integrated CLR mapping is better, but again each provider is allowed to support translation or not, so until runtime there is no way to know if the query will translate or not (2) linq2db package has better support for some things missing in EF Core like (recursive) CTEs and window functions, but probably not for db specific functions.

Comment: Can you please help me with this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68734040/problem-in-filtering-the-data-from-the-same-table

Comment: You can use the value converter (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions) as another option. This uses SQL Server CAST to convert string to dates though. So it uses the logins default language format.

If you can't change the login default language format then you have to run SET LANGUAGE "British English" (or your desired language) if the date format isn't the default US MM/dd/yyyy format. See here for more https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-language-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 6):

Speaking about weird solutions, I have noticed that using

```
(DateTime)(object)t.Date
```

inside the query does the job.

For example :

```
dbContext.Table.Max(t => (DateTime)(object)t.Date);
```

Will work perfectly.
I guess there's a little black magic behind this, and it will only work for most "direct" date formats and cultures conversions. I'll check later with SQL profiler or another solution what kind of SQL it emits.

Comment: This is the equivalent of `CAST(mycolumn AS DATE)` which won't allow you to specify a style like `CONVERT` does. As long as your string will `CAST` to a date though this will work as expected

Comment: @GarethD this is what I was expecting to find. It works but clearly I would not trust it too much, because it's heavily dependent of Culture and so...

Comment: Yeah, what I call the "double cast trick" (you can find it in some other my posts here) is another (and more general) approach which translates to SqlServer *default* data type conversions, which in general might not be the format used when storing numeric/date/time data as text.

Comment: works with integers stored as text too, just FYI