# The data types xml and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to fetch the value from xml data type column (SQL Server) using LINQ expression and Entity Core Framework
[image]
[image]

```
productDbContext.ProductSizeGuideLanguages.Any(i =>
                           i.SizeGuide.Equals("Some String")).Should().BeTrue();
```

Here is ProductDbContext:

```
public virtual DbSet<ProductSizeGuideLanguage> ProductSizeGuideLanguages { get; set; }
```

---

```
public class ProductSizeGuideLanguage
    {
        public int ProductSizeGuideId { get; set; }
        public int LanguageId { get; set; }
        public string SizeGuide { get; set; }
    }
```

---

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ProductSizeGuideLanguage>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => new { e.ProductSizeGuideId, e.LanguageId });

                entity.ToTable("ProductSizeGuideLanguage");

                entity.Property(e => e.ProductSizeGuideId)
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                    .HasColumnName("ProductSizeGuideID");

                entity.Property(e => e.LanguageId).HasColumnName("LanguageID");

                entity.Property(e => e.SizeGuide)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnType("xml");
            });
```

The error that i get is  `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : The data types xml and nvarchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.`
I'd appreciate if someone can help me with that issue

**UPDATE**

**1**. I've added Conversion in modelbuilder

```
internal class ProductSizeGuideLanguageEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ProductSizeGuideLanguage>
        {
            public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ProductSizeGuideLanguage> builder)
            {
                builder.HasKey( e => new { e.ProductSizeGuideId, e.LanguageId });
                builder.ToTable("ProductSizeGuideLanguage");
                
                builder.Property(e => e.ProductSizeGuideId)
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                    .HasColumnName("ProductSizeGuideID");
                
                builder.Property(e => e.LanguageId).HasColumnName("LanguageID");
                
                builder.Property(e => e.SizeGuide)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasConversion(xml => xml.ToString(),
                        xml => xml != null ? XElement.Parse(xml) : null)
                    .HasColumnType("xml");

                
            }
        }
```

---

**2**. Added ApplyConfiguration to OnModelCreating method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ProductSizeGuideLanguageEntityTypeConfiguration());              
        }
```

---

**3.** Changed SizeGuide data type to XElement

```
public class ProductSizeGuideLanguage
    {
        public int ProductSizeGuideId { get; set; }
        public int LanguageId { get; set; }
        public XElement SizeGuide { get; set; }
    }
```

And now i'm getting the error once i fetch first row from SQL DB:

```
var result = productDbContext.ProductSizeGuideLanguages.First():
```

> System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type
> 'System.Int16' to type 'System.Int32'.
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int32()    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetInt32(Int32 i)    at
> lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext ,
> SingleQueryResultCoordinator )    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext() at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at
> lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext )    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression
> query)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression
> expression)    at System.Linq.Queryable.First[TSource](IQueryable`1
> source)

Comment: Check this answer and correct to your case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68729840/10646316

Comment: Not sure how it's related to/from xml conversion

Comment: What is not related? How to convert XML to string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While EF will expect to cast XML to a `string` in the entity, as far as the database mapping is concerned it is an XML data type and SQL won't compare XML with a `nvarchar`. (what the string parameter would resolve to) You typically aren't going to search for a match on an entire XML definition, if you do, you may as well store the XML in the database as an `nvarchar(MAX)`

Normally you would want to search for a string value *within* the resulting XML. If that is the case then this article might help. (EF Core)

https://www.robkennedy.com/how-query-sql-server-xml-data-type-columns-in-entity-framework-core-3-x/

Alternatively, if you just want to inspect and test for a rough match an option would be to materialize the entities then perform the check:

```
var pgLanguages = productDbContext.ProductSizeGuideLanguages
    .Where(x => x.LanguageId == languageId)
    .ToList();


pgLanguages.Any(i => i.SizeGuide.Equals("Some String"))
    .Should().BeTrue(); // This does an Object-Linq against the string rather than EF-Linq resolving to SQL.
```

Note that this is an odd thing to test as it is testing the database data state. This might be valuable as an integration test if there is a meaningful `Where` condition to cover. As it was in the example it is simply asserting the database had an expected XML content which isn't the purpose of an integration test, and definitely not the purpose of a unit test.

Edit: Relating to the second exception, this would be due to the SmallInt data type for the Language ID. In your configuration you need to tell EF to expect the server data type:

```
builder.Property(e => e.LanguageId)
    .HasColumnName("LanguageID")
    .HasColumnType("smallint");
```

... which should cover that exception.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I've added the update to my question and stuck with the following error

Comment: I've added an update which should help with that remaining type conversion error.

Comment: Awesome!!! It works now! Thanks a lot Steve, I do appreciate your help and definitely will vote up your answer