# Problem in filtering the data from the same table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I have a class like below :

```
 public class MasterTransaction 
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public int? SubTransactionId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("SubTransactionId")]
        public virtual MasterTransaction SubTransaction { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<CommissionForManager> CommissionForManager { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class CommissionForManager
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ManagerId { get; set; }
        public decimal CommissionMoney { get; set; }
        
         public int MasterTransactionId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("MasterTransactionId")]
        public virtual MasterTransaction MasterTransaction { get; set; }
    }
```

`MasterTransaction` will store all the master transactions.
`CommissionForManager` table stores data related to all the transactions from where the Manager is getting a commission.

**Sample Data :**

```
MasterTransaction:

Id   EmployeeId     SubTransactionId
50   100            null  //100 is normal employee            
51   101            50    //101 is a Manager
52   102            null


CommissionForManager:

Id  ManagerId   CommissionMoney MasterTransactionId
1   101         5000            50  
2   101         6000            52
```

Now Manager creates transaction from a transaction of Employee and in that case "`SubTransactionId`" column will hold the `TransactionId` of that transaction.

**For example:** Manager 101 created a transaction from a transaction 50 hence `SubTransactionId` holds value 50.

So I want to get list of transactions where Manager is getting commission but those particular transactions shouldnt be referenced in "`SubTransactionId`" column.

**For ex:** Transaction Id = 50 and 51 because 51 is created from 50 so I want to ignore both. I only want Transaction 52 because it is not being referenced in "`SubTransactionId`" column in another Transaction.

Query :

```
string searchString;
int managerId;
var query = context.CommissionForManager.Where(c => c.CommissionMoney > 0)
                                        .Where(c=> c.MasterTransaction.Employee.EmployeeName.Contains(searchString));
                                        
if (managerId > 0)
    query = query.Where(c=>c.ManagerId == managerId);
    
return query.ToList();
```

But here, I am not getting how do I make another search of Transaction Id in the SubTransactionId of the same MasterTransaction table?

Can someone please help me or guide me through :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - but those particular transactions shouldn't be referenced in "SubTransactionId" column

and

> - For ex: Transaction Id = 50 and 51 because 51 is created from 50 so I want to ignore both

The second doesn't really match the first requirement. Also `SubTransactionId` is poorly chosen name since it gives an impression of a pointer (reference) to some *child*, while in fact it seems to have *parent* reference semantics.

So if the second statement is correct, then the requirement can be formulated as follows: *"include only transactions which have (1) no parent **and** (2) no child transactions"*.

The first condition is easy checked through navigation property, and the other needs subquery on the corresponding `DbSet` (remember it is queryable, so resolves to table access inside the LINQ to Entities query).

e.g. (skipping the initial part which applies other filters)

```cs
query = query.Where(c =>
    c.MasterTransaction.SubTransctionId == null // (1)
    &&
    !context.Set<MasterTransaction>().Any(t => t.SubTransactionId == c.MasterTransactionId) // (2)
);
```

The dilemma/issue for the question seems to be because of the lack of the inverse navigation property in the model. If you have it (as you should, since it's helping understanding the relationship better and property querying it from both sides), i.e. something like

```cs
public class MasterTransaction 
{
    // ...
    public virtual ICollection<MasterTransaction> ChildTransactions { get; set; }
}
```

then the second condition would be simply

```cs
!c.MasterTransaction.ChildTransactions.Any() // (2)
```

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me like as usual :).Thank you so much for a nice and comprehensive answer with a good explanation too. Sorry for not putting my words properly in the question as sometimes I struggle to do it. This indeed work as expected. I just have 1 question in my mind that is it going to be slow if MasterTransaction  table have lots of data like millions of transaction for example? Just wondering :)

Comment: Hi buddy :) PK and FKs are usually indexed, so seeks are by FK (index range seeks) are pretty fast.

Answer (score 2):

This will select no rows from CommissionForManager where the MasterTransactionId appears in the SubTransactionId column of MasterTransaction

```
var query = context.CommissionForManager.Where(c => c.CommissionMoney > 0)
    .Where(c=> c.MasterTransaction.Employee.EmployeeName.Contains(searchString))
    .Where(c => !context.MasterTransaction.Where(row => row.SubTransactionId == c.MasterTransactionId).Any());
```

This code will do the same as above but generate a left outer join instead of a nested select:

```
            var query = from c in context.CommissionForManagers
                     join m in context.MasterTransactions on c.MasterTransactionId equals m.SubTransactionId
                     into joined from j in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()      // Without this a inner join will be performed instead of a left join
                     where c.CommissionMoney > 0
                     && j == null                   // Select only rows that havent been joined to a MasterTransactions row by SubTransactionId
                     //&& c.MasterTransactions.Employee.EmployeeName.Contains(searchString)
                     select c;
```

Generated SQL:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[ManagerId] AS [ManagerId], 
[Extent1].[CommissionMoney] AS [CommissionMoney], 
[Extent1].[MasterTransactionId] AS [MasterTransactionId]
FROM  [dbo].[CommissionForManager] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[MasterTransaction] AS [Extent2] ON ([Extent1].[MasterTransactionId] = [Extent2].[SubTransactionId]) OR (([Extent1].[MasterTransactionId] IS NULL) AND ([Extent2].[SubTransactionId] IS NULL))
WHERE ([Extent1].[CommissionMoney] > 0) AND ([Extent2].[Id] IS NULL)
```

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me :). Is it going to be slow if MasterTransaction table have lots of data like millions of transaction for example?

Comment: It might be slow with many millions. As @IvanStoev said, creating an index on the SubTransactionId  column of the MasterTransaction table would be the best way to remedy this.
But also the original code generates a nested select statement which I have heard is not as efficient as a join. I added some new code that will generate a left outer join instead.