# What does casting a string to DateTime in an Entity Framework Core LINQ query return?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, datetime

My application uses Entity Framework Core to load data from an SQL database. To avoid loading all data entries of my table `Schedule` and filter them afterwards, I would like to filter them in the database query by comparing the `Schedule.Date` entry, which is a string, to a previously created `DateTime` object named `targetDate`. Since it is not possible to directly use `DateTime.Parse` to convert `Schedule.Date` to a `DateTime` in this query, I instead cast it to an `object` and then `DateTime` explicitly. The following line represents what I'm doing:

```
Schedule schedule = _context.Schedule.Where(s => (DateTime)(object)s.Date >= targetDate).First();
```

This works fine for now. However, I don't want to run into problems later, so I need to understand which format the cast to `DateTime` uses in this case. Though the dates in the database are strings, they are all provided in the format `en-US` and casting them appears to use just this format, which would be great. How can I be sure that it always uses this format and how is the format to be used determined when using a cast like this?

Comment: The best solution to have `Schedule.Date` as [Date and Time data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Why is it not possible to directly use `DateTime.Parse`? In fact, if you know the format, I'd go directly for `DateTime.ParseExact`.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I would agree, but it is not possible for me to change the data type in the database.

Comment: @Nyerguds It throws an exception because EF cannot translate DateTime.Parse into a database query. Otherwise I would do this.

Comment: I advise you to use an SQL tracer to see what _actual_ query is sent to the database for what you have, then; that'll make it a lot easier to determine whether it's doing something potentially dangerous.

Comment: What is the specific exception it throws if you use the parse? That's useful information to put in your question.

Comment: @Nyerguds You're right. But this will not answer answer my question in its entirety. This is more about how the object is converted by whatever function does it in EF. I need to know if anything out of my sight can affect the conversion such that it always works the way I need it.

Comment: Oh, there are absolutely factors out of your sight that can affect that. Run it on a computer with a different default date format and it might already mess up. I've encountered that problem first hand. (Sadly the entire database connection system on that was a black box and all we could do was "fix it in the Windows settings".)

Comment: @Nyerguds The exception tells me that a LINQ expression using DateTime.Parse cannot be translated to SQL. It is pretty much what is asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68728498/convert-string-to-datetime-in-linq-query-with-entity-framework-core
But that's not my question. I'm not necessarily looking for an alternative solution. My intention is to understand exactly what's happening in my example because I was not able to find it out myself.

Comment: @Nyerguds The fact that DateTime may work differently on another computer is exactly why I want to know what happens here. I have had my fair share of trouble with DateTime already and I'm looking to improve my understanding of it and related components as well as EF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using SQL Server

> Though the dates in the database are strings,

Which is bad for a number of reasons.  Here you'll require a table scan to convert all the strings to dates to perform the comparison.

> they are all provided in the format en-US and casting them appears to use just this format, which would be great.  How can I be sure that it always uses this format and how is the format to be used determined when using a cast like this?

The conversion is done in SQL Server which will convert strings to dates based on the current [language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-language-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) of the connection.

Comment: I agree that it was a mistake to not use the datetime data type for these columns! But your answer lead me in the right direction. The conversion is performed with the default language of the user in the session. Since I connect with 'sa' I was able to influence the result of the DateTime cast by changing their language.