# InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression

Tags: .net, linq, asp.net-core

I'm using ef to query to databse
my query is to get a date from database (string type), convert it to date type and compare it to another date

```
 var res = _context.Course.Where(a => DateTime.ParseExact(a.CourseStart, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) > fromDate).ToList();
```

and the result is always InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression  'DbSet()
.Where(c => DateTime.ParseExact(
s: c.CourseStart,
format: "MM/dd/yyyy",
provider: __InvariantCulture_0) > __fromDate_1)' could not be translated.

Comment: Are you able to modify the database schema to use a more appropriate field type? That would be better than parsing strings all the time to start with.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't touch or modify the database struct, I just have to provide a entity framework / linq query

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/functions doesn't suggest anything, unfortunately. How many courses are there? Would it be feasible to perform the filtering locally?

Comment: @JonSkeet I filtred them locally but I'm not satisfied with this solution I want to filter them with linq directly

Comment: Fundamentally there's a conflict there: your database isn't set up in a way that makes filtering there simple. You *may* be able to use an Entity Framework "escape hatch" of some description to include raw SQL to perform the conversion, but basically you should expect to run into problems like this when the schema is inappropriate for the data :(

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql for putting raw SQL in there.

Comment: here is how to add [`Convert` sql function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68728498/convert-string-to-datetime-in-linq-query-with-entity-framework-core)  support to the EF core; as you have not provided the database you execute it angst I assume sql server; for your date pattern the style parameter must be 101 instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet() .Where(c => DateTime.ParseExact( s: c.CourseStart, format: "MM/dd/yyyy", provider: __InvariantCulture_0) > __fromDate_1)' could not be translated.

The reason is that implicit client evaluation has been disabled from EF Core 3.

You can switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to `AsEnumerable` like below:

```
var res = _context.Course.AsEnumerable()                //add here...
    .Where(a => DateTime.ParseExact(a.CourseStart, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) > fromDate)
    .ToList();
```