# EF Core expression tree CONVERT

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, expression-trees

I'm having trouble writing EF Core expression tree code that would be able to translate to MS SQL Server query utilizing all 3 parameters of its built-in `CONVERT` function (`CONVERT( type[(length)], expression [, style])` - for applying style when converting i.e. datetime to string.

I've managed to write query that translates to `CONVERT` in SQL, but only passes 2 arguments: `type` and `expression`:

```
Expression.Convert(
    Expression.Call(
        typeof(Convert),
        nameof(Convert.ToString),
        Type.EmptyTypes,
        Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, prop.Name)
    ),
    typeof(string)
);
```

However, if I try using `IFormatProvider` with `Convert.ToString()` method (that is, passing the following parameter: `Expression.Constant(format, typeof(IFormatProvider))` after `Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, prop.Name)`, I get exception which states that expression could not be translated to SQL query.

For the testing purposes, format variable is defined as: `var format = new CultureInfo("hr-HR");`.

Any help would be much appreciated. I'm using EF Core 7.0 and SQL Server.

Comment: Before building expression tree, check which expression is translatable to the SQL. Just use compiler.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv unfortunately I cannot find anything about EF Core's ability to translate `IFormatProvider` to MSSQL's argument `style (short)` - so I guess it's not translatable? I don't know weather its possible to call MSSQL's built-in `CONVERT` function without defining user-defined database function?

Comment: So, create right question. How to generate SQL Server `CONVERT` from EF Core. It is too early for generation dynamic Expression Tree.

Comment: It should be similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68728498/convert-string-to-datetime-in-linq-query-with-entity-framework-core/68729840#68729840

Answer (score 0):

As of EFCore 7 providing a `style` parameter to the CONVERT built-in function is not possible.

You can check which built in functions are translated and how [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/functions).

You can also see [this post](https://www.thinktecture.com/en/entity-framework-core/custom-functions-using-imethodcalltranslator-in-2-1/) about using an IMethodCallTranslator for building an extension yourself, though its an old one(2019). The actual EFCore CONVERT IMethodCallTranslator can be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore.SqlServer/Query/Internal/SqlServerConvertTranslator.cs).

FYI Instead of CONVERT you can(and probably should) just use DateTime's `ToString` method. It will work just fine in the final select of your query(top-level projection).